# What method should I send emails with airflow?

Tags: email, smtp, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I am REALLY new to Airflow, DAGs, the whole nine.

So I have a task where I need to email some data to a list of recipients.

Right now, I have a python function which will send emails, and I was gonna assign this function to a task in my DAG.

However, in the task I was given, I was told that an admin should be able to trigger the DAG, such that additional recipients can receive the data by passing their emails through the airflow configuration json. I am assuming this means, airflow.cfg.

I have been googling for advice, but it seems like most people set up the email section in their airflow.cfg file to just send them an email if there's an error in the dag, not to a list of recipients.

I want to know:

**-If I pass a list of email recipients through my airflow.cfg file, can I still assign this email sending process to a task in the DAG?**

Comment: Hey @nick_rinaldi, I wonder if my answer below was helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `params`, which is a dictionary that can be defined at DAG level parameters and remains accesible in every task. This way you can pass the list of recipients, and then use the [EmailOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/email/index.html) to send the emails.

From the UI:

[image: trigger_dag_with_params]

```py
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

    email_task = EmailOperator(
        to='{{ params.mail_recipients }}',
        task_id='email_task',
        subject='My subject',
        html_content=" Templated HTML content - Today is {{ ds }}"
    )
```

Remember to previously configure [SMTP block](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html#email-configuration) in Airflow settings. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107775/10569220) for details and examples using `params`.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Hey, sorry Nico, yes, that answered my question! Thanks!