# Using dag_run variables in airflow Dag

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use airflow variables to determine whether to execute a task or not. I have tried this and it's not working:

```
if '{{ params.year }}' == '{{ params.message }}':
     run_this = DummyOperator (
                task_id = 'dummy_dag'
               )
```

I was hoping to get some help making it work. Also is there a better way of doing something like this in airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to solve this, is with `BranchPythonOperator` to branch dynamically based on the provided DAG parameters. Consider this example:

Use `params` to provide the parameters to the DAG (could be also done from the UI), in this example: `{"enabled": True}`

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context, BranchPythonOperator

@dag(
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
    params={"enabled": True},
)
def branch_from_dag_params():
    def _print_enabled():
        context = get_current_context()
        enabled = context["params"].get("enabled", False)
        print(f"Task id: {context['ti'].task_id}")
        print(f"Enabled is: {enabled}")

    @task
    def task_a():
        _print_enabled()

    @task
    def task_b():
        _print_enabled()
```

Define a callable to the `BranchPythonOperator` in which you will perform your conditionals and return the next task to be executed. You can access the execution context variables from `**kwargs`. Also keep in mind that this operator should return a single *task_id* or a *list of task_ids* to follow downstream. Those resultant tasks should always be directly downstream from it.

```py
    def _get_task_run(ti, **kwargs):
        custom_param = kwargs["params"].get("enabled", False)

        if custom_param:
            return "task_a"
        else:
            return "task_b"

    branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="branch_task",
        python_callable=_get_task_run,
    )
    task_a_exec = task_a()
    task_b_exec = task_b()
    branch_task >> [task_a_exec, task_b_exec]
```

The result is that *task_a* gets executed and *task_b* is *skipped* :

[image: branch from dag params]

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=branch_from_dag_params
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=task_a
Task id: task_a
Enabled is: True
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

[Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.0/concepts/dags.html#branching)

Comment: This helps @NicoE. I didn't really think about the `BranchPythonOperator`. Works for my needs. So one can access the params either through `lkwargs` or `context`, correct?

Comment: @Kay Glad to hear that it worked! Short answer is yes, it could also be accessed from a custom operator or any execution context. You can find another examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107775/10569220)

Comment: oh wow, that's a very good one. I was had a question about accessing params from a custom operator and the link gives me ideas on how to approach it. Thanks @NicoE

Comment: @kay Thanks for the feedback! If you find it helpful, upvoting for responses is very appreciated.