# How to pass parameters to scheduled task in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I need a scheduled task in airflow to run with different parameters. One way would be to write different dags for different parameters, but i was wondering if there is a better way of doing this like how we pass parameters to manual trigger.

Comment: can you provide an example of the schedule you want the DAG to run on, and example of the different parameters you'd want for each run?

Comment: for example i have a module which collects a company data from an api. given a different base_url i can use the same module for collecting another companies data (they are using the same product and have exact same apis, just different urls). now if i make this url a parameter to dag, the same dag can be used for any company i want to collect data. but this is the case for manual trigger, i need this dag to run at 1 am for Company A and at 2 am for company B every day.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107775/10569220) for examples on how to pass params to a DAG. I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger issue with writing the same DAG with different URLs is that you're breaking the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. If you need different schedules and you don't want to repeat the code twice, you can take [this DAG factory idea](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-dag-factory-on-airflow-9a19ab84084c) and build your own factory for these two DAGs. You'll finally have two DAG files that invokes the same factory with the parameters of schedule (1 AM and 2 AM) and URL.