# Airflow how to set default values for dag_run.conf

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to setup an Airflow DAG that provides default values available from `dag_run.conf`. This works great when running the DAG from the webUI, using the "Run w/ Config" option. However when running on the schedule, the `dag_run.conf` dict is not present, and the task will fail, e.g.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'key1'
```

Below is an example job.

Is it possible to make it so that `dag_run.conf` always contains the dict defined by `params` here?

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import hours_ago
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta

def do_something(val1: str, val2: str) -> str:
    return f'echo vars are: "{val1}, {val2}"'

params = {
    'key1': 'def1',
    'key2': 'def2',        
}

default_args = {
    'retries': 0,
}

with DAG(
    'template_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1),
    start_date=hours_ago(1),
    params = params,
) as dag:

    hello_t = BashOperator(
        task_id='example-command',
        bash_command=do_something('{{dag_run.conf["key1"]}}', '{{dag_run.conf["key2"]}}'),
        config=params,
    )
```

The closest I've seen is in [For Apache Airflow, How can I pass the parameters when manually trigger DAG via CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663534/for-apache-airflow-how-can-i-pass-the-parameters-when-manually-trigger-dag-via/53686174#53686174), however there they leverage Jinja and if/else - which would require defining these default parameters twice. I'd like to define them only once.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use DAG [params](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/params.html) to achieve what you are looking for:

> params (dict) – a dictionary of DAG level parameters that are made accessible in templates, namespaced under params. These params can be overridden at the task level.

You can define `params` at DAG or Task levels and also add or modify them from the UI in the *Trigger DAG w/ config* section.

**Example DAG:**

```py
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_dag_params",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *",
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    params={"param1": "first_param"},
    catchup=False,
)
with dag:

    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task", bash_command="echo bash_task: {{ params.param1 }}"
    )
```

**Output log**:

```
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,808] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_dag_params.bash_task 2021-10-02T23:15:00+00:00 [running]> on host worker_01
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,867] {taskinstance.py:1302} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=example_dag_params
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=bash_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-10-02T23:15:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2021-10-02T23:15:00+00:00
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,870] {subprocess.py:52} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,871] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'echo bash_task: first_param']
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,884] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Output:
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,886] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - bash_task: first_param
[2021-10-02 20:23:25,887] {subprocess.py:82} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

From the logs, notice that the `dag_run` is *scheduled* and the params are still there.

You can find a more extensive example on using parameters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107775/10569220).

Hope that works for you!

Comment: This works, thanks! Odd that the Trigger page & docs suggests using `dag_run.conf`, when IMHO this is clearly a more sensible pattern

Comment: I found this post helpful: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/25948

Comment: If someone is looking to use these params inside a `@task`, `context['params'][my_param_key]` is helpful.
https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-context

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python get() method to safeguard accessing a key in your config.

CODE:

```
# key not found example
...
with DAG as dag_run: # alias your dag so we can reference it
   conf_somekeyvalue = "{{ 
   dag_run.conf.get('keywhichdoesnotexist','val_if_key_not_found') }}"

# returns 'val_if_key_not_found'
```

```
# key found example
# assume your airflow run config looks like this { "keywhicdoesexist": "keywhicdoesexist_value_here" }

...
with DAG as dag_run:
   conf_somekeyvalue = "{{ 
   dag_run.conf.get('keywhicdoesexist','val_if_key_not_found') }}"

# returns 'keywhicdoesexist_value_here'
```

This will allow you to pop in a key in runs you need (like initial loads) and feel safe when it is not present.
I also like that it seems to resolve on dag run and we don't need to jump through hoops to find values