# How to pass a conf to a scheduled DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api, airflow-webserver

When the DAG is triggered manually there are multiple ways to pass the config. It could be done from the UI, via the airflow CLI using `--conf` argument & using the REST API.

But when a DAG is scheduled using a cron expression, the DAG always fails because the tasks in the DAG are expecting the values from `conf`.

Is there a DAG level configuration which can be used to set "default" values for `conf` values (WITHOUT doing a null check in the Python code itself and hardcoding a default value)

The reason I do not want to do this null check in the code itself is because I want the `conf` keys & default values to be exposed via an Airflow API if possible

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69421066/10569220) answers just what you are asking, check it out.