# How to force Airflow not to put single quotes around rendered name in PostgresOperator?

Tags: python, formatting, airflow

I'm using the Airflow PostgresOperator with argument `parameters` in order to replace the table name of my sql query with the one contained in my dictionary. For example:

```
create_table = PostgresOperator(sql='DROP TABLE if exists %(my_table)s;',
                                parameters={'my_table':'my_name'},...)
```

Problem is when operator is executed, the rendered sql is `DROP TABLE if exists 'my_name'` and not `DROP TABLE if exists my_name` as expected (and of course this operation fails).

How to force Airflow not to put single quotes around rendered name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `params` instead of `parameters`, should work because `sql` is declared as a  templated field in the `PostgresOperator`.

```py
create_table = PostgresOperator(sql="DROP TABLE if exists {{ params.my_table }};",
                                params={'my_table':'my_name'},...)
```

I haven't test it, but there is a similar use case in the [providers-package documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html#the-complete-postgres-operator-dag).

Comment: Frankly I don't see why there are params and parameters. Anyway it's working with params, thank you !

Comment: Hey @Patrick Glad to hear that it worked! `params` comes from `BaseOperator` so it's accesible pretty much anywhere, also works when triggering DAGs from the UI, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107775/10569220).